# How do you get documents that are outside of your initial publications?

Tags: meteor

For example, let's say I have posts that are locked with a password with the following fields (some may not have a password):

```
{
  _id: String
  password: String,
  body: String,
  createdAt: Date
}
```

The posts with a password only have some metadata published and the posts without a password is completely published:

```
Meteor.publish('locked_posts', function() {
  return Posts.find({ password: { $exists: true } }, { fields: { createdAt: 1 } });
});

Meteor.publish('public_posts', function() {
  return Posts.find({ password: { $exists: false } });
});
```

The view looks like this:

```
{{ #each posts }}
  {{ #if password }}
    <input type="password">
  {{ else }}
    <div>{{ body }}</div>
  {{ /if }}
{{ /each }}
```

Inside a template, a user should be able to enter a post's password and get that post's body:

So do I re-publish that single post, for which the password was entered, with all the fields, and refresh the template to display this new post?

Comment: Yep, you re-publish. Either that or you use a method to fetch the data, but you lose the reactivity. [Meteorhacks](https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-mergebox) has already published a blog post about document merging through MergeBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you change this publish to include the password as an input parameter (maybe encrypted?).

```
Meteor.publish('locked_posts', function(id, password) {
  check(id, String);
  check(password, String);
  return Posts.find({_id: id, password: password }, { fields: { createdAt: 1 } });
});
```

Then, you can call `Meteor.subscribe('locked_posts', postId, somePassword)` from your client code where you want the additional fields to be provided.

Comment: Yup this works. Thanks! Is there a way to find out if the publication is empty? If it is empty, that means the password would be wrong and I would like to know that on the client side

Comment: You could throw a [Meteor.Error](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_error) from your publish method if the password doesn't match